# OpenGL: Is it possible to wrap around a vertex buffer?

Tags: java, opengl, attributes, vertex

I have two vertex buffers, one for XY co-ordinate data and one for UV data, passed to a shader as attributes.

```
XY_Data (Two Triangles)   : {  0f,  0f, 10f,  0f, 10f, 10f, 
                              50f, 50f, 60f, 50f, 60f, 60f }

UV_Data (Single Triangle) : {  0f,  0f, .5f,  0f,  1f, 1f  }
```

Is it possible to reuse the UV data for a single triangle when drawing two triangles, without having to extend the size of the buffer to match the XY Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older version, (assuming your openGL to java wrapper was a thin one) you got C-style undefined behavior. In other words *anything could happen* up to and including making demons come out of your nose. But it usually just means a crash or garbage on the screen.

In newer versions if one of the rubustness extensions are available then you won't get a crash but the values passed to the shader may still be garbage or just set to 0.

There is no way to reuse the UV data like that that doesn't involve using a sampler and slowing down the rendering. It's just easier to duplicate the data and be done with it.